# What is the proper way to convert a route parameter to an integer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am trying to pull an ID from the URL. My route looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

And the Action link and generated URL look like this:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink((string)link.Name, "Video", new { id = link.ID } )</li>
http://localhost:57762/Video/3 // <-- generated URL
```

Then we get to the controller:

```
public ActionResult Video()
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(RouteData.Values["id"].ToString());
    var treatment = Treatment.Find(id);
    ViewBag.Title = treatment.Name;
    ViewBag.Treatment = treatment;
    return View();
}
```

**Here's the weird part:**

The view renders everything correctly. I can access ViewBag.Treatment all day long and everything works as expected, but the second my browser finishes loading the view, Visual Studio throws this Exception:

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

**It is complaining about this line:**

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(RouteData.Values["id"].ToString());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmmm, why don't your ActionResult Video have an `int id`  parameter ? Something like `public ActionResult Video(int id)`

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus it is not necessary

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I don't think I fully understand your comment. But it looks like it might solve my problem. Can you post a complete answer?

Comment: @Selman22 What is not necessary?

Comment: @anwyatt defining a parameter (I said it to Raphael) because you already define it in the routeconfig.that should work I think.

Comment: @Selman22 not necessary, but it makes things easier than having to make a specific search on RouteData values, no ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus yes but this should work.I still don't understand why it doesn't work. anwyatt are you sure that the generated url is `http://localhost:57762/Video/3`  instead of `http://localhost:57762/Video?id=3` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the controller you get to specify what the `id` is:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
  return View();
}

public ActionResult Index2(string id)
{
  return View();
}
```

The model binder will convert the value automatically (or throw a yellow screen if it can't).

A couple of tips taken from [6 Tips for ASP.NET MVC Model Binding](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx).  (I'd like to copy the whole thing here, but really only tip one is relevant).

> Tip #1: Prefer Binding Over Request.Form

If you are writing your actions like this ..

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
    recipe.Name = Request.Form["Name"];

    // ...

    return View();
}
```

.. then you are doing it all wrong. The model binder can save you from using the Request and HttpContext properties – those properties make the action harder to read and harder to test. One step up would be to use a FormCollection parameter instead:

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection values)
{
    Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
    recipe.Name = values["Name"];      

    // ...

    return View();
}
```

With the FormCollection you don’t have to dig into the Request object, and sometimes you need this low level of control. But, if all of your data is in Request.Form, route data, or the URL query string, then you can let model binding work its magic:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create(Recipe newRecipe)
{            
    // ...

    return View();
}
```

In this example, the model binder will create your newRecipe object and populate it with data it finds in the request (by matching up data with the recipe’s property names). It’s pure auto-magic. There are many ways to [customize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute_members.aspx) the binding process with “white lists”, “black lists”, prefixes, and marker interfaces. For more control over when the binding takes place you can use the  UpdateModel and TryUpdateModel methods. Just beware of unintentional binding – see Justin Etheredge’s [Think Before You Bind](http://www.codethinked.com/post/2009/01/08/ASPNET-MVC-Think-Before-You-Bind.aspx).

Comment: +1: note that in OP's sample this used as `Index` (or "home") action too. Consider to comment on how to deal with `/` (root without `id`) url.

Comment: Sounds like you want an answer to a question the OP didn't ask.

Comment: I believe the *The model binder will convert the value automatically (or throw a yellow screen if it can't).* is fair warning.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the framework to do this for you with it's binding capabilities:

```
public ActionResult Video(int? id)
```

No need to extract id explicity from route data.

Answer (score 2):

You want something like following if you really expect that parameter to be optional:

```
   public ActionResult Video(int? id) ...
```

But it may be easier to have separate action for cases when you actually have `id` and adjust routes accordingly.

Comment: It is important to note that in this example if the model binder can't bind string to nullable int so `/Home/Index/Test` will still throw an error, but on the positive side, if the url parameter is empty/null then this is a good way to test if an Id was passed (`.HasValue = false` if no value was passed).